# Node sqlite3 when to close db

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I cannot figure out when to close a db in node-sqlite3, or really how to use the package in general. It seems if I run this, I get "no such table:rooms". Eventually after running it enough times, I might manage to make the table.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

class RoomManager{
    constructor(options){

        this.db = this._createDb();
        this.table = "rooms";

        this._createTable();
        this.addRoom({
            name : 'test3'
        }).getRooms()
        this.deleteRoom({
            name : 'test3'
        }).getRooms();

        return this;
    }

    _createDb() {
        return new sqlite3.Database('chat');
    }

    _createTable(){
        this.db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + this.table + " (name TEXT, size INT)");
        return this;
    }

    addRoom(options){
         this.db.run("INSERT INTO " + this.table + " (name, size) VALUES ($name, $size)", {
            $name : options.name,
            $size : options.size || 1000
        });
        return this;
    }

    getRooms(){
        this.db.all("SELECT rowid, name, size FROM " + this.table, function(err, rows) {
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                console.log(row.rowid + ": " + row.name + " - " + row.size);
            });
        });
        return this;
    }

    getRoom(options){
        if(options.name){
            this.db.get("SELECT * FROM " + this.table + " WHERE name = $name", {
                $name : options.name
            }, function(err, row){
                return row;
            });
        }
    }

    deleteRoom(options){
        this.db.run("DELETE FROM " + this.table + " WHERE name = $name", {
            $name : options.name
        });
        return this;
    }
}

module.exports = RoomManager;
```

Comment: If you run *what*? You haven't shown the code that actually uses this `RoomManager` class.

Comment: simply `new RoomManager()`. As a test the constructor creates a table, adds rows, gets rows, deletes rows, and gets again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that Node is asynchronous. So, you must wait end of command by callback function. e.g.

```
this.db.run(query, params, function(err) {
   if (err)
      return console.log(err);

   // do next query here
})
```

Sqlite module can control flow by [**db.serialize**](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow). Imho it's useless in common cases. Better use async module or promises for it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But what do you mean it's useless? What async module do you mean?

Comment: `sqlite.serialize` is uncomfortable if I want sequense of queries, e.g. insert new record, get id of it, do smth with this id. Async (https://github.com/caolan/async) is one of popular module to execute list of asynchronous command.